# angularjs with angular-ui modal form

Tags: angularjs

Hi i am beginner for angularJS and i am showing angular-ui modal form when click on button and have to add new user but i am really confusing how to handle and how to do this scenario and i tried below code but its not working can some one help me better way to do this

My requirement i want to open modal form for adding new user and when i click save button i need to add that new user in my array

### main.js

```
    // create the module, pass in modules it depends on
    var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ui.bootstrap']);
    // $modal service is now available via the ui.bootstrap module we passed in to our module
    app.controller('myController', ['$scope', '$uibModal', '$log',
        function ($scope, $uibModal, $log) {
            $scope.newUser = {};
            $scope.info = "";
            $scope.users = [
                { username: "rimon", fullName: "Md. Mamunur Rashid Rimon", email: "rimonmath@gmail.com" },
                { username: "shamim", fullName: "Md. Tamim Hossain", email: "shamim@gmail.com" },
                { username: "tamim", fullName: "Tamim Iqbal", email: "tamim@gmail.com" }
            ];

            $scope.addUser = function () {
                var modalInstance = $uibModal.open({
                    templateUrl: 'add_user.html',
                    controller: 'ModalInstanceCtrl',
                });
                modalInstance.result.then(function (selectedItem) {
                    $scope.selected = selectedItem;
                }, function () {
                    $log.info('Modal dismissed at: ' + new Date());
                });
            }

            $scope.saveUser = function () {
                console.log("Saving...");
                $scope.users.push($scope.newUser);
                $scope.info = "New User Added Successfully!";
                $scope.newUser = {};
            };

            $scope.selectUser = function (user) {
                $scope.clickedUser = user;
            };

            $scope.deleteUser = function () {
                console.log($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser));
                $scope.users.splice($scope.users.indexOf($scope.clickedUser), 1);
                $scope.info = "User Deleted Successfully!";
            };

            $scope.clearInfo = function () {
                $scope.info = "";
            };
        }]);


   angular.module('myApp').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($scope,$uibModalInstance) {
    $scope.saveUser = function () {
        alert("You clicked the ok button.");
        $uibModalInstance.close();
    };

    $scope.close = function () {
        alert("You clicked the cancel button.");
        $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
});
```

### Form.html

```
<div>
    <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">New User Registration</h4>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
        <form class="form-horizontal">
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Username</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Username" ng-model="newUser.username">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Email</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Email" ng-model="newUser.email">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="inputEmail3" class="col-sm-2 control-label">Full Name</label>
                <div class="col-sm-10">
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="inputEmail3" placeholder="Full Name" ng-model="newUser.fullName">
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <div class="col-sm-offset-2 col-sm-10">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" ng-click="saveUser();">Save</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </form>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" ng-click="close()">Close</button>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Is it showing any error on the F12 DevTools?

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance

Comment: i am getting above error and i am not sure the way i am doing correct please suggest

Comment: No one having idea about this?

Comment: If it's what I'm thinking you have to register your modal controller in the app declaration. Let me formulate an answer.

Comment: i followed this link https://www.formget.com/angularjs-popup/

Answer (score 0):

From what I see, your problem lies in your declaration of FormController.js please try to change this code :

```
app.controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', ['$scope','$modalInstance',function ($scope, $modalInstance) {
   $scope.close = function () {
       $modalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
    };
  $scope.saveUser = function(){
         //SUBMIT FORM HERE
  }

}]);
```

for this one :

```
angular.module('ui.bootstrap.demo').controller('ModalInstanceCtrl', function ($uibModalInstance, data) 
{
  var pc = this;
  pc.data = data;

  pc.ok = function () {
    //{...}
    alert("You clicked the ok button."); 
    $uibModalInstance.close();
  };

  pc.cancel = function () {
    //{...}
    alert("You clicked the cancel button."); 
    $uibModalInstance.dismiss('cancel');
  };
});
```

From your code I noticed that:

1. Your declaration of the modal controller misses the name of the main module app which sometimes is required.
2. you are using '$modalInstance' instead of $uibModalInstance

For further reference go [here](https://embed.plnkr.co/plunk/XWNBvo). Please try these changes and let me know if it works!

Comment: Hi i updated my question and i followed your code but still i getting exception when i tapped on button

Comment: Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.7.5/$injector/unpr?p0=%24modalInstanceProvider%20%3C-%20%24modalInstance%20%3C-%20ModalInstanceCtrl

Comment: Where did i do mi stack?

Comment: Which version of boostrap are you using?and if its possible let me see where you added the scripts. Something basically its wrong with the reference, bad called or bad placed.

Comment: <script src="js/ui-bootstrap-tpls-2.5.0.min.js"></script>   <link href="//netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">

Comment: Can you please have a look at my issue?

Comment: Use the same version that reference link I put in the solution has, and please name your controllers in the same we can get closer to the problem or solve it.

Comment: angular.js:14328 ReferenceError: ModalInstanceCtrl is not defined

Comment: getting above error if i used same version you used